# SQL dbcc opentran versus sysprocesses

Tags: sql-server

I don't understand how can happen that command `DBCC OPENTRAN` shows no open transactions,
but select from DMV sysprocesses shows me one open transaction

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE open_tran = 1
```

Could anyone explain how is it possible?
DBCC OPENTRAN is executed on the right database.

Comment: FYI, you *really* shouldn't be using `sys.sysprocesses` anymore (or any of the `sys.sys{name}` objects); it's for compatibility with SQL Server **2000** databases. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysprocesses-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: `opentran` looks at the current database; `sysprocesses` is instance-wide. Also it's very hard to correlate the _single database_id value_ exposed by that deprecated view since a query (and hence the transaction) can affect more than one database. Take a look at [`sp_whoisactive`](http://whoisactive.com/) and see [why you shouldn't use `sysprocesses` here](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/02/sql-performance/deprecated-features-1) (in addition to the warning in the documentation).